# How to center text vertically inside a div with dynamically changing height?

Tags: html, dynamic, text, center

I am trying to make a website navbar using divs instead of the usual lists. The divs are inline-blocks and on hover, the navbar expands. This should cause all the inner divs to expand `(height:100%)`, while retaining centered text. I want to use only html and css.

One way is to set `line-height` and use `vertical-align:middle`. But since the div expands vertically in a dynamic manner, I cannot give a static value to `line-height`. I tried using `line-height:100%`, but that doesn't seem to help!

---

The html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="headContainer">
      <a href="/HOME"><div id="logo"></div></a>
        <div id="rightBar">
            <div class="navelement"><a href="HOME">HOME</a></div>
            <div class="navelement"><a href="HOME">HOME</a></div>
            <div class="navelement"><a href="HOME">HOME</a></div>
            <div class="navelement"><a href="HOME">HOME</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </body>
```

The Css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#headContainer {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#headContainer:hover {
    height: 100px; /*Dynamically change navbar height on hover, thus changing the height of all children*/
}

#rightBar {
    line-height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    width:80%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navelement{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    border:2px solid cyan;
}
```

---

The JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/GBz3s/1/

Comment: So many elements. Which ones do you want to expand exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GBz3s/2/)

you need to give `display: inline-table;` to `.navelement` and

`display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to `.navelement a`

CSS

```
.navelement{
    display: inline-table;
    height: 100%;
    border:2px solid cyan;
}
.navelement a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know - inline-table is apparently not supported by IE7, just in case you were planning to offer support for it. (http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/display%3Ainline-table)

Comment: That was superfast, and superawesome!
But I unserstand that table attributes are not compatible with <IE8.
How can I support those browsers? (I don't mind makin a separate CSS file for them)

Comment: inline-table is supported in IE8 and above....I dont think we need to care about IE7 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a precise height for your nav, then you can use a hack with padding by declaring the height, floating the divs, doing some math, and making adjustments accordingly. You can see an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Perry_/GBz3s/3/

```
.navelement{
    float: left;
    width: 24.25%; 
    border:2px solid cyan;
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}

    #rightBar:hover .navelement {
        height: 90px;
        padding: 45px 0 0 0;
    }
```

Comment: The position relative isn't necessary. I was going to try something else. You can also move the hover to the outermost header class.